# Will downloading Xcode only from dmg file cause any issue?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I am trying to `download` `Xcode` from the `appstore` and after filling stupid billing information to none, which I don't think was required in the first place, the download is taking forever.

Will downloading `dmg` file only cause any kind of issue?

I mean other than the fact that it won't automatically `update Xcode`, will there be any other issue by doing so?

Comment: Do not download dmg file outside from iTunesConnect. In past Xcode Malware Contained apps were banned by Apple, including the developer program. It's painful process specially outside USA takes forever for everyone , always download software from legit source.

Comment: Yea, i am trying to download from here: https://developer.apple.com/downloads

Comment: But I was being skeptical about Xcode not being downloaded from the appStore. Apart from auto-update feature, will that affect any thing else?

Comment: It's completely OK to download from developer.apple.com, after all, that's the same source the App Store uses. Downloading from any other source that is not apple.com is risky though.

Comment: dont' download outside from *.apple.com. Search on internet about xcodeghost issue in past

Comment: Thank You guys :) Any idea why downloading from app Store is taking forever? Plus, Now we even need to fill the billing form and update payment method to none :/

Comment: yes it's very slow ( no option ). It doesn't matter how fast is your internet speed. Keep it on after 5-6 hours you will see results

Comment: Download the DMG file, and download the updated DMG when relevant. I spent 3 days downloading Xcode once with a fibre connection, this issue is in Apple's court.